# regex php match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I would like to get a very simple date ('day_month' such as 'Monday january') with just one regex. Here is what I try :

```
$str = $argv[1];
$day = "[Mm]onday|[Tt]uesday|...|[Ss]unday";
$month = "|[Jj]anuary|[Ff]ebruary|...|[Dd]ecembre";
$pattern = "'~".$day.$month."~'";

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $array) == 0)
    print("wrong format");
else
    print_r($array);
```

I try this with "Monday January", expecting to get Monday and January, but I only get "Monday", same thing for "Monday Tuesday". I could use two preg_function but I am sur that I can do with just one call to preg_match_all. Could you help me to understand my mistake ?

Comment: Remove the single quote before and after `~`. The if statement also doesn't make sense, reread the documentation. You're relying on PHP's dynamic nature...

Comment: If thats the actual code and you are using the '...' instead of the rest of the days then that part matches 3 random characters breaking the rest of your matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match *2* entities in the input string, but you build just 1-entity return pattern with alternatives (`1|2|3|4` will return just 1 result). To fix this, we should capture 2 groups of characters that are separated by a space in your case.

You can use this code to get both:

```
<?php
  $str = "Monday January";
  $day = "[Mm]onday|[Tt]uesday|[Ss]unday";
  $month = "[Jj]anuary|[Ff]ebruary|[Dd]ecembre";
  $pattern = "~(" . $day . ")\s+(" . $month . ")~";

  if (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $array) == 0)
     print("wrong format");
  else
     print_r($array);
?>
```

[Sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQ3JELUVYOGtEY3M) output:

```
Array
(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [0] => Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            [0] => Monday January                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    [1] => Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            [0] => Monday                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    [2] => Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            [0] => January                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

)
```